# showing an equality involving sums

Tags: integration, combinatorics

> Show that for $n\geq 1, \sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^i}i {n\choose i} = -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}k$ by using the fact that $\int_0^1 x^i dx = \frac{1}{i+1}.$

I tried first using the binomial theorem to get the equality $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^i x^{i-1} {n\choose i} = \dfrac{(1-x)^n-1}{x},$ but I'm not sure how I can integrate $\dfrac{(1-x)^n - 1}x$ from $0$ to $1$. Integrating the LHS from $0$ to $1$ yields $\sum_{i=1}^n \dfrac{(-1)^i}i {n\choose i}$, so if I could integrate that, it'd be very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take into account that, for $y=1-x$
$$
\int_0^1\frac{(1-x)^n-1}{x}dx=-\int_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy
$$
and one of the relations that [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) satisfy
$$
H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\int_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy
$$
The last one can be easily proved
$$
\int_0^1\frac{1-y^n}{1-y}dy=
\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}y^kdy=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left.\frac{y^{k+1}}{k+1}\right|_0^1=
\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+1}=
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}
$$